# Using all processor cores when exporting map to TIFF using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, parallel-processing

By default, ArcGIS Desktop uses only one processor core when you export a map. Esri help talks about the possibility of setting environment parameters for geoprocessing tools, but found nothing about exporting maps. For larger map layouts, the export process on a single core can take a long time.

How can I enable more than one core to do the export process?

Comment: How exactly would parallel map export work?  Multiple writers to a single file? Some tasks just don't support parallel operation.

Comment: @Vince This is not a parallel export of maps - this is a parallel operation of all cores for the process of exporting maps to tiff.

Comment: Based on your comment bellow, can you give us example of what you are trying to export? 10 minute is indeed weird unless this is (really) old machine or you are printing very detailed layers at very high resolution.

Comment: @Martan I can not provide You with the project, as the data is the property of the customer works. All layers that are rendered are vector layers. The data consists of several thousand polygons with forest inventory data. Typically, there are up to 15 different layers in project.

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to the [Parallel Processing](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/parallel-processing-factor.htm) environment. As you've mentioned, this environment is only for **tools**. Only *some* tools support this environment. You'll need to look at individual tool's help page to see if they support that. Note, the only options to export a map are through the buttons in the software, or using arcpy *functions*, meaning there are no export tools. To the best of my knowledge, no arcpy functions support parallel processing.

In short, there is no setting or option you can enable to make ArcGIS use more than 1 core when doing a map export. You've tagged your question as arcgis-desktop, meaning you could be using ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro. At this point, its incredibly unlikely ArcMap will be enhanced to make use of multiple cores when doing an export. ArcGIS Pro *may* simply make use of multiple cores (again, no setting to enable or disable): it does for various operations. I've never seen a list of what operations work over multiple cores. If it doesn't for exporting, and you feel strongly, I'd suggest adding an idea to ideas.arcgis.com with this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Apparently so I will wait for 10 minutes while the export on my computer. The only strange thing is that no one has ever complained about it before. This is extremely important, because this process takes a very long time if you do many maps.